# Open-source C++ scanning library

Tags: c++, static, automation, analysis

**Rationale**: In my day-to-day C++ code development, I frequently need to
answer basic questions such as who calls what in a very large C++ code
base that is frequently changing. But, I also need to have some
automated way to exactly identify what the code is doing around a
particular area of code.  "grep" tools such as Cscope are useful (and
I use them heavily already), but are not C++-language-aware: They
don't give any way to identify the types and kinds of lexical
environment of a given use of a type or function a such way that is
conducive to automation (even if said automation is limited to
"read-only" operations such as code browsing and navigation, but I'm
asking for much more than that below).

**Question**: Does there exist already an open-source C/C++-based library
(native, not managed, not Microsoft- or Linux-specific) that can
statically scan or analyze a large tree of C++ code, and can produce
result sets that answer detailed questions such as:

- What functions are called by some supplied function?
- What functions make use of this supplied type?
- Ditto the above questions if C++ classes or class templates are involved.

The result set should provide some sort of "handle". I should be able
to feed that handle back to the library to perform the following types
of introspection:

- What is the byte offset into the file where the reference was made?
- What is the reference into the abstract syntax tree (AST) of that
  reference, so that I can inspect surrounding code constructs? And
  each AST entity would also have file path, byte-offset, and
  type-info data associated with it, so that I could recursively walk
  up the graph of callers or referrers to do useful operations.

The answer should meet the following requirements:

- **API**: The API exposed must be one of the following:

  - C or C++ and probably is "C handle" or C++-class-instance-based
    (and if it is, must be generic C o C++ code and not Microsoft- or
    Linux-specific code constructs unless it is to meet specifics of
    the given platform), or
  - Command-line standard input and standard output based.
- **C++ aware**: Is not limited to C code, but understands C++ language
  constructs in minute detail including awareness of inter-class
  inheritance relationships and C++ templates.
- **Fast**: Should scan large code bases significantly faster than
  compiling the entire code base from scratch. This probably needs to
  be relaxed, but only if **Incremental result retrieval** and **Resilient
  to small code changes** requirements are fully met below.
- **Provide Result counts**: I should be able to ask "How many results
  would you provide to some request (and no don't send me all of the
  results)?" that responds on the order of less than 3 seconds versus
  having to retrieve all results for any given question. If it takes
  too long to get that answer, then wastes development time. This is
  coupled with the next requirement.
- **Incremental result retrieval**: I should be able to then ask "Give me
  just the next N results of this request", and then a handle to the
  result set so that I can ask the question repeatedly, thus
  incrementally pulling out the results in stages. This means I
  should not have to wait for the entire result set before seeing
  some subset of all of the results. And that I can cancel the
  operation safely if I have seen enough results. Reason: I need to
  answer the question: "What is the build or development impact of
  changing some particular function signature?"
- **Resilient to small code changes**: If I change a header or source
  file, I should not have to wait for the entire code base to be
  rescanned, but only that header or source file
  rescanned. Rescanning should be quick. E.g., don't do what cscope
  requires you to do, which is to rescan the entire code base for
  small changes. It is understood that if you change a header, then
  scanning can take longer since other files that include that header
  would have to be rescanned.
- **IDE Agnostic**: Is text editor agnostic (don't make me use a specific
  text editor; I've made my choice already, thank you!)
- **Platform Agnostic**: Is platform-agnostic (don't make me only use it
  on Linux or only on Windows, as I have to use both of those
  platforms in my daily grind, but I need the tool to be useful on
  both as I have code sandboxes on both platforms).
- **Non-binary**: Should not cost me anything other than time to download
  and compile the library and all of its dependencies.
- **Not trial-ware**.
- **Actively Supported**: It is likely that sending help requests to mailing lists
  or associated forums is likely to get a response in less than 2
  days.
- **Network agnostic**: Databases the library builds should be able to be used directly on
  a network from 32-bit and 64-bit systems, both Linux and Windows
  interchangeably, at the same time, and do not embed hardcoded paths
  to filesystems that would otherwise "root" the database to a
  particular network.
- **Build environment agnostic**: Does not require intimate knowledge of my build environment, with
  the notable exception of possibly requiring knowledge of compiler
  supplied CPP macro definitions (e.g. -Dmacro=value).

Comment: This question looks like you'd buy something that fits your specifications... but no, you want it for free :) Or what do you mean by "open-source" actually?

Comment: I don't think that static analysis is what you actually want. Static Analysis is about checking for program invariants and reporting potential errors in programs. What you want is Indexing.

Comment: @matthieu-m: You are absolutely right. I have since removed the "static analysis" in the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that [CLang Index](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/libIndex.html) is a close fit. However I don't think that it stores data in a database.

Anyway the CLang framework offer what you actually need to build a tool tailored to your needs, if only because of its C, C++ and Objective-C parsing / indexing capabitilies. And since it's provided as a set of reusable libraries... it was crafted for being developed on!

Comment: That looks like it is quite close to what I am looking for. Experimentation is needed to see how robust libindex is for indexing large scale C++ code bases, however.

Answer (score 3):

I have to admit that I haven't used either because I work with a lot of Microsoft-specific code that uses Microsoft compiler extensions that i don't expect them to understand, but the two open source analyzers I'm aware of are [Mozilla Pork](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Pork) and the [Clang Analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).

Comment: Even though Mozilla Pork looks promising as an example of finding and fixing problematic areas of code, I think the Clang Analyzer (and the libindex library it might be built upon) is more promising.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't say either way.  However, the Clang Analyzer looks to me to be easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for results of code analysis (metrics, graphs, ...) why not use a tool (instead of API) to do that? If you can, I suggest you to take a look at [Understand](http://www.scitools.com/).

It's not free (there's a trial version) but I found it very useful.

Comment: I had tried feeding my large set of C++ code to Understand in the past, but their parser hung on me. Since it was binary, I could not figure out why it was hanging, so I gave up on it.  Oh and it doesn't meet the requirements of non-trial-ware.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Doxygen with GraphViz could be the answer of some of your constraints but not all,for example the analysis of Doxygen is not incremental.

Comment: Doxygen also hangs up on my source code, so it can't be an option.  Besides, it generates HTML files which require a browser to use, and what I'm looking for is an API that I can use to drive symbol lookups and other operations.

Comment: Doxygen generate also xml files where you can find all what you need.